# Commenting syntax for x86 AT&T syntax assembly

Tags: assembly, comments, gnu-assembler, att, intel-syntax

The Intel syntax has comments using the semicolon. When I switched to AT&T, it actually tried to interpret the comments.

What is the comment syntax for AT&T assembly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Comments for at&t assembler are:

```
 # this is a comment
 /* this is a comment */
```

According to [the fourth result Google gave me](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2008-11/msg00698.html)

`//` and `/* */` comments are only supported in `.S` files because GCC runs the C preprocessor on them before assembling.  For `.s` files, the actual assembler itself (`as`) only handles `#` as a comment character, for x86.

For some other ISAs, GAS uses other comment characters, for example `@` for ARM.

Answer (score 9):

### GNU AS Comments

The following are handled by `as` directly. (Not the C preprocessor.)

- `#` Comments - Works as a "rest of line" comment.

  Important Caveat: `#` is also the GCC preprocessor directive symbol. The preprocessor runs first, so this means that if you *are* running it,

  ```
  # include comments in your code to get full credit
  ```

  at the beginning of the line (whitespaces don't count) will give you `error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>` with gcc, even with a space after the `#`.

  However, these are case-sensitive, so capitalizing `# Include` actually works:

  ```
  # Include comments in your code to get full credit
  ```

  While it is generally good practice to capitalize the first letter of your comments anyway, you can use `##` as a just-in-case measure. (Just don't use it on any lines that are part of a `#define` macro because `##` is also the token pasting operator.)
- `/` comments - Start of line comment

  These may *only* be used at the start of a line (after whitespace removal).

  ```
  / This is OK
  xor %eax, %eax / This is *not* ok
  ```

### C-style Comments (preprocessor)

These work if the C preprocessor is run on the source file.

In most architectures, the following are supported:

- `// Rest of line comment` works pretty much as you'd expect from C.

  In rare cases this causes problems with `.` pseudo-ops. To work around this, I just use a block comment or just move the comment to the preceding line.
- `/* Use this for block comments */`. I currently haven't run into any issues with this.

### So what do I use?

- If you're *not* allowed to preprocess everything, choose one of the GNU AS Comment styles, `#` or `/`.
- If you're sure you *will* preprocess everything, it may be safer to go with the C-style comments `//` and `/**/` to avoid preprocessor issues. However, if you keep in mind the hidden gotchas, you should be ok.
- If you're concerned about having to handle both, choose either `/` or `##` so you don't have to worry about the preprocessor or lack thereof on any one file. `##` is more versatile, but may lead to messier code.
- Whatever the case may be, choose one and be consistent.

Comment: You don't *have* to preprocess AT&T syntax files.  `gcc` does when compiling `.S` files, but not `.s`.  Writing comments that are safe for use with or without CPP is a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try # or // or /* */. Might work